# C# optimization calling a method and returning its value for each item in the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

currently, I have a list of items that I want to loop thru. For each item number I want to call another method and return its value to another list.
Below is the implemented code by me:

```
List<SomeClass> lst = new List<SomeClass>();

foreach (var i in someList)
{
   lst.AddRange(obj.ReturnsAnEnumerableOf_MyClass(i.someId));
}
```

I'm not sure if calling a method within the `AddRange` method is a good idea or not. 
So, I want to optimize this into something better using a line like below code:

```
 var j = someList.ForEach(i => obj.ReturnsAnEnumerableOf_MyClass(i.someId));
```

But, I get below error by executing above one liner code:

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly typed variable

.

How can I optimize the above code?

Comment: why do people come here to down vote a question with an already accepted answer without providing a reason for doing so? You are not really helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN page, the `ForEach` method returns `void`. That is the cause for the error you get.

If you want the convert the above code to a one-liner, you can use:

```
var j = someList.SelectMany(i => obj.ReturnsAnEnumerableOf_MyClass(i.someId)).ToList();
```

`j` will be a `List<T>` instance, where `T` is the type of the list `ReturnsAnEnumerableOf_MyClass` returns.

Also, as a side note, there isn't much optimization going on around here: performance wise, both ways should take the same time. It's more of a preference of readability.

The performance should be identical because in both ways there the same amount of operations (which are the number of operations that `ReturnAsEnumerableOf_MyClass()` multiplied by the length of `someList`) is being carried out, so there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Is the foreach faster or the SelectMany faster ?

Comment: just a follow up question. Why did you use SelectMany here instead of a Select?

Comment: Your method, `ReturnsAnEnumerableOf_MyClass` returns a `List<T>`. The `Select` method will aggregate those lists (generated for each object in `someList`) to a list of lists (i.e `IEnumerable<List<T>>`). On the other hand, `SelectMany()` **flattens** this collection of lists to a single collection: `IEnumerable<T>`.